# SyntaxError: invalid syntax sem razão aparente

Tags: python-2.7

Em python, estava a fazer uma função na tentativa de fazer um programa de clientes:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E obtive este erro, não sabendo bem porquê:

[image: erro]

Alguém me pode ajudar?

Comment: Poste sempre o seu código, não imagens

Comment: muito obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

O `if` e o `else` estão sem o sinal de dois pontos.

Exemplo:

```
if(condição):
   # Código
elif(condição):
   # Código
else:
   # Código
```